# Amazon RDS: How can I limit the RDS instance access to AWS Lambda functions and TO My computer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-security-group, aws-sam

I am developing a REST API with `AWS Lambda`, `API Gateway` and `Amazon RDS(MySQL)`. I am using AWS Sam to do the configurations and all.

I created the database by visiting the amazon website's RDS section. It working fine as expected. I also managed to deploy the Lambda functions and get them connected with the database.

My database is set to `Publicly Accessible = Yes`

But, I noticed the database is open to the whole world. See the below images.

**Security Group Rules**

[image]

**Inside the default security group**

[image]

Well, this looks scary, I have no security.

In case of database security, what I need is this.

1. All of my Lambda functions can access the database
2. MySQL WorkBench can access the database
3. I test this locally, so I may need to run the lambda locally and connect to RDS

In case you need, below is my **template.yaml** file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  abcd-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for abcd-restapi

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 100

Resources:
  GetAllAccountTypesLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: abcd-restapi
      Handler: com.abcd.dao.accountingtype.GetAllAccountTypesLambda::getAllAccountTypes
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 1024
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accounttype
            Method: get
```

What should I do to remove the "whole world free access" and implement the access I mentioned above ?

**-----------UPDATE----------**

This is my security group now, after following John's advice. But Lambda cant access the database, MySQL workbench can

[image]

Lambda-SG security group

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Amazon RDS database is in a **public subnet** and is set to `Publicly Accessible = Yes`, then you can **use Security Groups to control access to the database server**.

- Put a Security Group on the Lambda functions (`Lambda-SG`) with default "Allow All Outbound" settings
- Put a Security Group on the RDS database (`DB-SG`) with Inbound rules that permit access on port 3306 (MySQL) from `Lambda-SG`. That is, `DB-SG` specifically references `Lambda-SG`.
- Add your own public IP address to `DB-SG` Inbound rules to allow access on port 3306 (MySQL).

While a publicly-accessible database is not ideal from a security perspective, the Security Group will help you limit access to the server. The database server will also require authentication to connect to the database, which is an additional layer of security.

**Private Subnet vs Public Subnet**

From [The layered defense approach to security - IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=security-layered-defense-approach):

> Using a layered approach when you plan your Internet security strategy ensures that an attacker who penetrates one layer of defense will be stopped by a subsequent layer.

Resources in a **private subnet** are not accessible from the Internet. This is an important concept used in all corporate networks. It introduces additional hurdles for legitimate users (eg requiring VPN connections or connections via a Bastion server), but is worthwhile when considering the security of your resources.

The benefit of using a **public subnet** is purely to make access simpler for *You*. However, it also makes access simpler for unauthorized users by removing a layer of security. Yes, **Security Groups** are a firewall that can limit access, but it might be misconfigured or permit too much access. This is your choice to make, based on your **risk appetite**.

The **more secure method would be to put your database in a private subnet**. Then, if you need to access the database from outside the VPC you would need to use a VPN connection or use Port Forwarding through a Bastion server (with a private keypair used for authentication).

Comment: Thank you John. To do what you meant, how can I put a security group? When I open Lambda in AWS website, i do not see a feature called `security groups`

Comment: Also does this means the `default` vps that RDS is using should be changed?

Comment: VPS? Do you mean VPC? You can't "change" the VPC for Amazon RDS. You would need to launch a new cluster if you want to change VPCs.

Comment: Thanks John. I followed your advice, created 2 security groups. One is attached to RDS now. But remember, my RDS also already connected with the `default` security group which allows the full access. My questions are 1) After the attaching the `DB-SG` to RDS, shall I de-attach it from the default? 2) I do not understand how to assign the `Lambda-SG` to lambda function.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the Default security group from the RDS database since it is granting access from everywhere. You would need to create a Security Group for the Lambda function (here I call it `Lambda-SG`). Then, in an Inbound rule on the `DB-SG`, you can select a Security Group in the **Source** field -- type `sg` and a list of security groups will appear. Just select the one used by the Lambda function(s).

Comment: I have done that. Since I could not find a way to remove the `default` security group I changed the `deault` with the settings you mentined for `DB-SG`. Now I can access the databae from MySQL Workbench but not from Lambda. I think in Lambda I have to do something? Edit the `templace.yaml` file or in `AWS -> Lambda` section tell the Lambda to use the security group `Lambda-SG` ? I have posted a image of my security group in ,my question.

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function configured to use the same VPC as the RDS database? This is necessary for the security group to recognize the traffic. If the Lambda function is _not_ configured to use the VPC, then the security group cannot recognize the incoming request as coming from the Lambda function.

Comment: When I go to Lambda configaration page, it says `This function isn't connected to a VPC.` I tried connecting by adding the subnets the RDS using, with `Lambda-SG` security group, then it said `The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2`

Comment: Do some web searches. You'll see some answers to this error. For example: [Solution! The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2 - Software Engineering Authority](https://ao.ms/the-provided-execution-role-does-not-have-permissions-to-call-createnetworkinterface-on-ec2/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The link worked. In the link they are providing these policies in the aws web console, Instead, do you know how I can give them directly in the `.yaml` file? I created a specific question for this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68409728/how-to-add-policies-to-aws-lambda-function-using-the-yaml-file

Comment: Thank you for great support, my issue is now sorted. I need another advice from you please. Users also say that creating a `private subnet` is a solution, instead of making the database `publicly accessible`. But we make it accessible with security from security groups, so it is limited. What is the real difference in these two methods?

Comment: I have extended my answer to provide a comparison of the two methods.

Comment: Thank you. How about turning on "public" only when I wanted to, and turning it off when I no longer need it? I don't know if it's possible with RDS, but if it is, what's the situation?

Comment: You can use the **Modify** function to change this setting, which would take a few minutes to take effect. However, I would not recommend this as the database would still be in the Public Subnet. That setting only modifies the ability for the DNS Name to resolve publicly. If set to NO, then the DNS Name is not reachable from the Internet.

Comment: Wow nice info. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. All of my Lambda functions can access the database

The most secure way is to put your RDS in a **private subnet** and associate your functions with your VPC. The functions must be in private subnet as well if you want them to also access internet through NAT.

> 2. MySQL WorkBench can access the database

If you put your RDS in private subent, you won't be able to access it directly from outside of VPC. The most secure way is to setup VPN or **ssh tunnel** between your local workstation and the VPC. ssh tunnel is the easiest to setup and most commonly used for testing and development.

> 3. I test this locally, so I may need to run the lambda locally and connect to RDS

Same as point 2. Need VPN or ssh tunnel.

Comment: Thank you for the help, appreciate it. I managed to handle it by creating security groups and making the database public. Can you please explain the difference between your way and making the database public and controlling access via security groups ?

Comment: @JustCause  SGs are always used, whether rds is public or private. But having it public is not a good security practice. The good practice is to have it fully private.

Comment: Appreciate it. In case of this, how MYSQL Workbench connects to this? Via SSH?

Comment: @JustCause Ssh tunnel would be most commonly used for that.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Just curious, what about me keeping the RDS public when I want to access and turning it off other times? If that's possible I mean?

Comment: @JustCause I think you have to decide what you want to do. Your entire question is about your database being public which is bad security practice. But after all these answer, you seem to still want to keep it public. I don't know what else I can advise. You can't have it both ways. Its either public or not.

Comment: Anyway, why that is because I'm using aws-sam, and I need to make sure the development environment can connect to cloud without a hassle. Also I should be graphically access the dB, that's why I want to maintain some sort of public state you know... That's why I thought of keeping it public when our local environment is accessing and keeping it private in other times...